# VMware Workstation 15.1 doesn't work for Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: kernel, vmware

I tried to open VMware after 10 days and it stopped working for me. As not so good in Ubuntu, I tried to resolve the problem with solutions in a couple of posts, but the same issue occurred, showing error message while running from terminal. There are couple of files attached as well with the logs and with the screen shot of the error message:

[image: screenshot showing VMware Kernel Module Updater dialog box and a terminal window with text related to the build]

The message in the dialog box is:

> Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.

The contents of the terminal are:

```
mohit@:~/Downloads$ vmware
Gtk-Message: 12:22:38.926: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: 12:22:43.386: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o' failed
Makefile:1606: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic'
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'vmmon.ko' failed
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only/userif.o' failed
Makefile:1606: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic'
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-gBfrut/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
```

Please suggest what I can do to resolve this.

```
***LOG FILE MESSAGE**************************
2019-09-06T12:03:16.571+10:00| modconfig| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=6753 version=15.0.2 build=build-10952284 option=Release
2019-09-06T12:03:16.571+10:00| modconfig| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.571+10:00| modconfig| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2019-09-06T12:03:16.571+10:00| modconfig| I125: Host is Linux 5.0.0-27-generic Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
2019-09-06T12:03:16.570+10:00| modconfig| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.570+10:00| modconfig| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.570+10:00| modconfig| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.570+10:00| modconfig| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/mohit/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.570+10:00| modconfig| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/mohit/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.570+10:00| modconfig| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/mohit/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.607+10:00| modconfig| I125: Initialized!  Lets do this thing...
2019-09-06T12:03:16.607+10:00| modconfig| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.607+10:00| modconfig| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.607+10:00| modconfig| I125: Setting header path for 5.0.0-27-generic to "/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include".
2019-09-06T12:03:16.607+10:00| modconfig| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.0.0-27-generic".
2019-09-06T12:03:16.607+10:00| modconfig| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2019-09-06T12:03:16.615+10:00| modconfig| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.0.0-27-generic".
2019-09-06T12:03:16.615+10:00| modconfig| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.0.0-27-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2019-09-06T12:03:16.725+10:00| modconfig| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/Module.symvers
2019-09-06T12:03:16.725+10:00| modconfig| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.742+10:00| modconfig| I125: Read 23264 symbol versions
2019-09-06T12:03:16.742+10:00| modconfig| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.742+10:00| modconfig| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.742+10:00| modconfig| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.742+10:00| modconfig| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.742+10:00| modconfig| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.758+10:00| modconfig| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "5.0.0-27-generic".
2019-09-06T12:03:16.758+10:00| modconfig| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "5.0.0-27-generic".
2019-09-06T12:03:16.758+10:00| modconfig| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2019-09-06T12:03:16.760+10:00| modconfig| I125: Got gcc version "7".
2019-09-06T12:03:16.760+10:00| modconfig| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2019-09-06T12:03:16.760+10:00| modconfig| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2019-09-06T12:03:17.149+10:00| modconfig| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2019-09-06T12:03:17.149+10:00| modconfig| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2019-09-06T12:03:17.153+10:00| modconfig| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2019-09-06T12:03:17.153+10:00| modconfig| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j12 -C /tmp/modconfig-vKs08g/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2019-09-06T12:03:18.526+10:00| modconfig| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2019-09-06T12:03:18.526+10:00| modconfig| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2019-09-06T12:03:18.526+10:00| modconfig| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2019-09-06T12:03:18.529+10:00| modconfig| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2019-09-06T12:03:18.529+10:00| modconfig| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j12 -C /tmp/modconfig-vKs08g/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2019-09-06T12:03:20.123+10:00| modconfig| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2019-09-06T12:03:20.132+10:00| modconfig| I125: We are now shutdown.  Ready to die!
******************
```

Comment: Your first line is confusing. Did it work 10 days ago? Based on the info you posted, I can't imagine that it did.

Comment: yes it worked 10 days ago

Comment: Try rebooting into a previous kernel; the 5.0.0-27 series was just released a few days ago.

Comment: @ajgringo619 still the same outcome boot from 5.0.0.25 , will try with 4.15.0-60

Comment: try to reinstall vmware, it helped for me

Comment: @ingvar  already did that, tried with different versions as well. Is there any good alternative to VMware workstation

Comment: anyways downloaded virtualbox for now and it is working fine.

Comment: Have you ever tried Kvm?

Comment: @ingvar No , Is it good ?